# SQL Server : violation of PK_Key Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am getting this error when I try and register a user for a app I'm building.

[image]

This is the github repo for the code: https://github.com/krl87/tears

and this is the bak file for the DB: *drive.google(.)com/file/d/0B-i80yr4BB7pcXE1djdnRnlKdW8/view?usp=sharing*

TIA!

EDIT: I ENDED UP FIGURING OUT WHAT THE ISSUE WAS, TURNS OUT I HAD AUTO INCREMENTS OFF ON THE PK. :/

Comment: Perhaps you could make a modicum of effort and post which bit of code is throwing the error, and the table DDL, and the data being entered into the screen.

Comment: It says you have duplicated key in the users table which is against the constraint. Modify your User entity in your model in that way the UserID will be a [Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Key).

Comment: post relevant codes(like SaveChanges()) rather linking to project ..as more time will be wasted searching function and codes if entire project is posted

Comment: seems like an assignment!

Comment: I can't restore your db file in my sqlserver test... Can you confirm that you UserID column is PK and Identity ?